# How to get products and the number of buys each has with one SQL query?

Tags: sql

`Buy` has a foreign key `product_id`.

So in addition to `SELECT * FROM products;` we are interested in getting the number of buys each product has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Join**

```
SELECT Products.*, COUNT(Buy.ID) AS Bought
FROM products
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Buy ON products.ID = Buy.product_id
GROUP BY Buy.product_id
```

**Subquery**

```
SELECT 
    Products.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Buy WHERE product_id = Products.ID) AS Bought
FROM products
```

Comment: Thanks! A side question: Any idea about the performance between the two?

Comment: Like any good DB answer, it depends. Typically the JOIN will be the best bet. I would try them both and look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(buy.product_id) FROM product p INNER JOIN buy ON buy.product_id = p.id GROUP BY buy.product_id
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.*,COUNT(b.product_id) FROM products p
INNER JOIN buy b ON p.id=b.product_id
GROUP BY b.product_id
```

Thats about all I can offer with the info you've posted.  Table structure of both would help a ton if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks randomguy. I fixed the above. Unable to test unfortunately.